# Energy Preservation for Light in Blender

Tags: lighting

I'm currently looking into using physically meaningful renders from point lights in Blender 3.6 LTS. In particular, I need the resulting linear .exr images to adhere to energy preservation (linearity) of lighting, i.e., their values must scale linear with respect to the light in the scene and it has to be additive.

In quick experiments (as easy as adding a single point light source to the default Blender scene with the cube, setting the rendering output to linear / .exr and scaling the light source power to double the value) the linearity does not hold up. I have instead also experimented with using emission objects and scaling the emission there, but also do not observe linearly scaling results. However, by using emitting objects, I was able to verify that the object surfaces of the emitting objects themselves correctly scale linearly with the emission 'strength').

Any hints on how to debug this further?